# a lex program that find the longest string and then reverse it

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

Hi i am having a problem in this program i dont know how can i get the longest string and then reverse it plz help me.the R.E which i have in mind is this

```
[a-zA-z]{8,}
```

but here i am assigning limit but i want to do it with out limit also sugget me how can i reverse it

```
  %{

 char string;
%}
longest [a-zA-z]{8,} 


%%
{longest}  { string=yytext;}


%%
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
# include <iostream.h>
void main()
{  yylex();
    cout << "Longest string is = " << string<<endl;
    cout << "longest string in reverse is " << strrev(string) << endl;

}

int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

Comment: Show input and expected output

Comment: giving me compiler error  cant not convert char* to char

Comment: You have `char string;` in header. Must be `char* string`.

Comment: i have change char string[200]; now all the other errors are gone just one error is remain which lvalue is required..

Answer (score 1):

`lex` couldn't get strings inside an input stream, it recognizes character sequences from the begin till the end. So you need regex's for both your "longest strings" and other tokens (separators).

Then you need a `result` string variable. Every time recognizing the token, you should compare lengths of `result` and token. If token is longer, then it must be stored as `result`.

**longest.lex**

```
%option nounistd
%option noyywrap

%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* longest;
%}

longest     [a-zA-Z]{8,}

%%

{longest}   {
            if (yyleng > strlen(longest)) {
                longest = (char*)realloc(longest, yyleng + 1);
                strcpy(longest, yytext);
            }
        }
<*>.|\n     /* skip all unrecognized text */

%%

int main() {
    longest = (char*)malloc(1);
    longest[0] = '\0';
    yylex();
    printf("Longest string is '%s'\n", longest);
    strrev(longest);
    printf("Longest reverse string is '%s'\n", longest);
    free(longest);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i get your point but how can i compare new and the old token string

Comment: Do you need C or C++ solution?

Comment: Well, wait about 10 minutes.

Comment: See my answer. It took longer than I expected.

Comment: Thnx Sir can you tell me why did u use %option nounistd
%option noyywrap and also <br/>                                                              longest = (char*)realloc(longest, yyleng + 1); and this line to longest = (char*)malloc(1);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69275/discussion-between-usama-lucky-and-mark-shevchenko).

Comment: In short, I've 'win_flex` so I've to add some additional thins (like options) in the .lex source. `malloc` and `realloc` both are used to to avoid a buffer overflow. Unfortunately the address arithmetic is not so simple, and it can't be described in two paragraphs. I advise you to read the K&R book, it contains everything you need.

Comment: Do you know their alternative in turbo c

Comment: Turbo C has both of them. malloc/realloc are standard functions.

Comment: Sir can you please look at my this program & Tell the error plz...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061065/a-parser-program-for-the-following-grammer