# A parser program for the following grammar

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, yacc, lex

Write a parser (both Yacc and Lex files) that uses the following productions and actions:

```
S -> cSS    {print “x”}  
S -> a  {print “y”}  
S -> b  {print “z”}
```

Indicate the string that it will print when the input is `cacba`.

I am getting this error: when I give input to it, it says valid input and also says syntax error.

My Scanner Code is this

```
%{
   #include "prac.h"
%}
%%

[c] {return C; }
[a] {return A; }
[b] {return B;  }
[ \t]   ;
\n  { return 0; }
.   { return yytext[0]; }
%%

int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
}
```

And my yacc code is this:

```
%{
   #include <stdio.h>
%}
%token A B C
%%
statement: S    {printf("Valid Input"); }
;
S: C S S        {printf("Print x\n");} 
| A     {printf("Print y\n");} 
| B     {printf("Print z\n");} 
;
%%
int main()
{
    return yyparse();
}

yyerror(char *s)
{
    printf("\n%s\n",s);
    printf("Invalid Input");
    fprintf(stderr,"At line %d %s ",s,yylineno);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What input are you giving it?

Comment: Best guess -- you're running on windows, so you're getting a `\r` (carriage return) character before the newline which is causing your error.  Try adding `\r` to the `[ \t]` pattern to ignore it.

Comment: I removed my answer since it didn't seem to work for you. Still change your `fprintf()` statement to `fprintf(stderr, "At line %d %s", yylineno, s);` not that it will solve your problem.

Comment: @rici I am giving it input cacba but it says syantax error

Comment: @Cyclone yup cyclone i will give it a try

Comment: Usama: It works for me, so I think you should consider @ChrisDodd's suggestion

Comment: mean i should add \r int \t so the new regex for it will be [\r\t] Am i right ?@rici

Comment: @UsamaLucky - I can send you the complete code that worked for me, sadly some people are very quick to downvote =( and YES you can use regularexpression in the fashion I showed in lex, but some people ....

Comment: @rici - let's hope you will supply a valid answer =)

Comment: @UsamaLucky: chris suggests `[ \r\t]`. If you have Windows somewhere in the loop, I agree.

Comment: @Cyclone it will be really helpfull if u send me the complete working code my email is usamamashkoor@gmail.com

Comment: @UsamaLucky - Your email doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

([Comments converted to an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))

@ChrisDodd wrote:

> Best guess -- you're running on windows, so you're getting a `\r` (carriage return) character before the newline which is causing your error. Try adding `\r` to the `[ \t]` pattern to ignore it.

@Cyclone wrote:

> Change your `fprintf()` statement to `fprintf(stderr, "At line %d %s", yylineno, s);` not that it will solve your problem.

The OP wrote:

> You mean I should add `\r` into `\t` so the new regex for it will be `[\r\t]` Am I right ?

@rici wrote:

> @chris suggests `[ \r\t]`. If you have Windows somewhere in the loop, I agree.